# MYSQL: Create UNIQUE index for combination of three fields to prevent dupes

Tags: mysql, unique-index

In order to preserve a one-to-one ration between three fields, I would like to create a `UNIQUE` index on the three fields. In other words, for a table, `Reviews` if one field is `reviewid`, I would like to prevent instances where more than one `reviewid` is associated with a given `songid` for a given `userid`.

In fact, I would like to do this for several combinations `reviewid` and `songid`, `reviewid` and `artistid` and `reviewid` and `albumid` for a given `userid`.

I cannot change the data schema at this point.  While right now, I am trying to do this in PHP code, it would be better if MYSQL enforced the uniqueness through Indices to ensure one never slips through.

```
Reviews
reviewid (primary key)|text|songid|albumid|artistid|userid
1|great song|222|null|null|22
2|great album|null|333|null|22
3|great singer|null|null|444|22

//I want to exclude the following entry:
4|lousy song|222|null|null|22
```

I think this should be possible with a UNIQUE index on the fields in question, but I can't get MYSQL to accept this.  It says that you cannot have a Unique index and Primary index on the same field, in this case, reviewid.

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you just need separate unique keys on songId, artistid, and albumid. Since reviewId is the pk, if any songid appeared on multiple records it would necessarily be with a different reviewId. In fact, an index on both fields would accomplish the opposite of what you want, allowing multiple occurrences of songId as long as it was with a different reviewId; unique indexes on multiple fields ensure the *combination* is unique.

Edit: It's covered in the comments below, but the exact solution was that the unique indexes needed to be on the userId and the song/artist/album being reviewed; multiple reviews were allowed, just only once per user.

Comment: Sorry, I did not edit my question in time.  The issue crops up because there are multiple users.  If there was only one user, then a uniqueid for the songid should work as you suggest, however, with multiple users allowed to review a given song, then the issue remains.  Edited question above.

Comment: Ah, then the compound unique index should include the userId, not the reviewId. The reviewId really doesn't matter in this scenario.

Comment: I still have a problem.  As of now, the data has 0s in every instance where the review is for a different field, ie if the review is for an artist it shows a 0 in the songid field.  So there are a very large number of 0 entries for songid, artistid and albumid for a given userid which are preventing me from creating the Unique index. So the answer while correct for my question, did not solve the problem.  I will ask a separate question for the case of 0s.